# laravel validation on array and missing parameters

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-request

I have an array which I would like to be validated. The post json payload looks like this

```
{   
    "guid" : "d19b122dc48a4663e33eaa7c83993f7a40ae9329",
    "organization" : {
        "phone" : "0466144569",
        "email" : "test@test.com",
        "country" : "US",
        "language" : "en",
        "name" : "rockstar"
    },
    "user" : {
        "username" : "rockstar",
        "password" : "rockstarpassword",
        "consent" : {
            "gdpr": "true",
            "version": "consent_doc_2009"
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that, this payload can change in 4 different scenarios.

1) The whole payload exists. Just like the above example.

2) Where `organization` is missing.

```
{   
        "guid" : "d19b122dc48a4663e33eaa7c83993f7a40ae9329",
        "organization" : null
        "user" : {
            "username" : "rockstar",
            "password" : "rockstarpassword",
            "consent" : {
                "gdpr": "true",
                "version": "consent_doc_2009"
            }
        }
    }
```

3) Where `user` is missing.

```
  { 
        "guid" : "d19b122dc48a4663e33eaa7c83993f7a40ae9329",
        "organization" : {
            "phone" : "0466144569",
            "email" : "test@test.com",
            "country" : "US",
            "language" : "en",
            "name" : "rockstar"
        },
        "user" : null
        }
    }
```

4) Where `organization` and `user` is both missing.

```
 {  
        "guid" : "d19b122dc48a4663e33eaa7c83993f7a40ae9329",
        "organization" : null,
        "user" : null

    }
```

I have a laravel request class that validates this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class organizationCreation extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'guid' => 'required|string',
            'organization.name' => 'required_with:organisation|string|min:3',
            'organization.phone' => 'required_with:organisation|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|max:20',
            'organization.country' => 'required_with:organisation|max:2',
            'organization.language' => 'required_with:organisation|max:2',
            'organization.email' => 'required_with:organisation|string|max:255',
            'user.username' => 'required_with:user|string|max:255',
            'user.password' => 'required_with:user',
            'user.consent.gdpr' => 'required_with:user|boolean',
            'user.consent.version' => 'required_with:user|string|max:255',
        ];
    }
}
```

I tried the above validation, and used required_with, but then it looks like the validations fail, and I am not sure how to go forward with this validation that has 4 different rules.

I can separately validate them by checking the payload with `if` and not write code for it but I would like to do them all at once.

Comment: In which of the 4 scenario's does the validation fail? Or does it fail for every single one?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `required_with` tells us the following:

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only if any of the other specified fields are present.

In your case the fields are present, but they have `null` values. Would it be possible to not send the keys at all or do you not have control over the client consuming your API? In that case you could use a middleware for stripping out null-values instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't have control over the client API.

Comment: In that case you could write a middleware similar to [ConvertEmptyStringsToNull](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.html) or you could implement a custom validation rule as mentioned [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/validation-other-field-has-value?page=1#reply=168512).